# Out of dynamic memory in yy_create_buffer()

Tags: php, memory

Has anyone seen this error when working with a PHP application "out of dynamic memory in yy_create_buffer()"?

The error message that appears in the php error log is:
Fatal error: out of dynamic memory in yy_create_buffer() in Unknown on line 0

I have not been able to identify a reproducible case. Increasing memory_limit has no affect on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"yy_" is generally a prefix for methods created by the yacc parser generator. While I can't tell you how to solve it, I'd look to the size of your PHP pages as an issue. Do you have lots of includes?

Edit: I downloaded the source code for [Bison](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bison/bison-2.4.tar.gz) (the yacc clone used by Linux), and looked for yy_create_buffer. Seemed pretty harmless. There is a variable for that controls buffer size, but I don't see any command-line option to set it. It's possible that whatever you're using is calling directly into the Bison library and not properly cleaning up.

Answer (score 3):

set

memory_limit to -1

in your php.ini, for a workaround

or update your php version

should solve the problem